# How to use Office's diagnostics API

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

As per this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.diagnostics?view=outlook-js-preview), we can use office's diagnostic API to get host related information. Problem is that there is no example there to show how to use this API. If someone can give an example, please provide.
I need to get this info in my outlook addin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sets of diagnostics APIs. In both cases, the properties are available immediately, without calling an asynchronous API.

In Outlook, the [Office.Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.diagnostics?view=outlook-js-preview) object is available at `Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics`. And its properties are:

```
Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName
Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostVersion
Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.OWAView
```

In both Outlook and other Office add-in hosts, the [Office.context.diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=outlook-js-preview#diagnostics) API returns [similar information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.contextinformation?view=outlook-js-preview).

Answer (score 0):

The [Script Lab for Outlook add-ins](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-US/product/office/wa200001603), available free from AppSource, enable you to explore the Office JavaScript API while you're working in an Office program such as Excel or Outlook. Script Lab is a convenient tool to add to your development toolkit as you prototype and verify functionality you want in your own add-in.

Read more about that in the [Explore Office JavaScript API using Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) article.